# Inverse Galois problem for small groups

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory

I am looking for a list of all small groups (maybe order $\leq 20$) realized as the Galois groups of a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$, with proof.

Any idea where I could find these?  Partial answers or references would be helpful too.

Comment: I note that there are (up to isomorphism) $14$ groups of order $16$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best online reference I know of is *[A database for number fields](http://galoisdb.math.upb.de/home)* by Jürgen Klüners and Gunter Malle. The database also provides references. (I first found the database through [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105811/a-polynomial-whose-galois-group-is-d-8) MO question.)

In print, there are several excellent books related to the problem, at different degrees of accessibility. The most introductory, with many examples, is

> Helmut Völklein. **Groups as Galois groups. An introduction**. Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics, 53. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1996. [MR1405612 (98b:12003)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1405612).

You may also want to look at

> B. Heinrich Matzat. **Konstruktive Galoistheorie**. Lecture Notes in Mathematics, 1284. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1987. [MR1004467 (91a:12007)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1004467).
>
> Gunter Malle, and B. Heinrich Matzat. **Inverse Galois theory**. Springer Monographs in Mathematics. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1999. [MR1711577 (2000k:12004)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1711577).
>
> Jean-Pierre Serre. **Topics in Galois theory**. Second edition. With notes by Henri Darmon. Research Notes in Mathematics, 1. A K Peters, Ltd., Wellesley, MA, 2008. [MR2363329 (2008i:12010)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2363329). (See also [MR1162313 (94d:12006)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1162313) for a review of the first edition.)
>
> Christian U. Jensen, Arne Ledet, and Noriko Yui. **Generic polynomials. Constructive aspects of the inverse Galois problem**. Mathematical Sciences Research Institute Publications, 45. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2002. [MR1969648 (2004d:12007)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1969648).

All these books present specific examples together with the general theory. **Generic polynomials**, in particular, is concerned with *constructive* aspects and the question of identifying polynomials for specific groups.

As a complement, I suggest looking at [these](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70155/on-the-inverse-galois-problem) [two](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13851/the-inverse-galois-problem-and-the-monster) MO questions.