# Galois Groups of Polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Computing Galois groups of polynomials is a kind of standard thing to do in algebra, so I think this question goes without much further motivation.

It is known that every element of the Galois group is a permutation of the roots of the irreducible factors of some given polynomial. If we fix a labeling of the roots, this gives an injection from the Galois group into the symmetric group of the appropriate order, which is clearly a homomorphism, as both group operations are composition.

Since every group is a subgroup of a symmetric group, we have the natural question:

Is every group the Galois group of some polynomial (over $\mathbb Q$)?

Now it is also not hard to show using cyclotomic polynomials that every Abelian group is the Galois group for some polynomial over $\mathbb Q$, so in the abelian case, the answer is affirmative. What can be said in the remaining cases?

Comment: It is known that every FINITE group is the Galois group of some algebraic extension of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @Piquito: No it isn't, unless you know something we don't...

Answer (score 4):

This is known as the **inverse Galois problem** ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem)) and it has been extensively studied, with many partial results, though the problem remains unsolved in full generality.

Comment: This is really cool! Are there any standard results in this direction that you could provide a reference for? I'm on summer break and would love to read about this further.

Comment: Probably the first thing to take a look at is Hilbert's irreducibility theorem ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_irreducibility_theorem)). [This math.SE thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/290139/264) has some more references to read from.